# Why doesn't hive allow >, >= in JOIN clauses, but you can get around it with JOIN ON IF(a > b, 1, 0) = 1?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Just wondering why Hive disallows >, >= conditions in the JOIN clause but you can do `JOIN ON IF(a > b, 1, 0) = 1` to get around it.

Are there times where using `JOIN ON IF(a > b, 1, 0) = 1` is okay if performance isn't a problem?

Comment: I am using hive version 1.1.0-cdh5.4.2, I am not able to make hive non-equijoin work with IF condition. Although impala works with IF condition. Could you please let us know which hive version you are using to make non-equijoin work with IF condition?

Answer (score 0):

Because:

> Hive does not support join conditions that are not equality
>   conditions as it is very difficult to express such conditions as a
>   map/reduce job.

From Hive [LanguageManuel](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins)